# No gridding for a single paragraph (ConTeXt)?

Tags: context, paragraphs, grid-typesetting

Is there a possibility to deactive `grid=yes` in the text for a single paragraph only? It should be something like `\nogrid{ paragraph.... }`. There is `\placeongrid{}` - but this does not allow page-breaking, so the whole paragraph is set as one on a new page, if breaking is needed. I think no minexample is needed here, any paragraph does it.

Answer (score 1):

You just put stuff in a `\vbox` and `\vsplit` it to break across pages.  To not mess up the gridding around, use `\snaptogrid` when placing the boxes.

```
\showgrid
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\unexpanded\def\startnogrid{%
  \setbox\scratchboxone=\vbox\bgroup}

\unexpanded\def\stopnogrid{%
  \egroup
  \scratchdimen=\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\topskip\relax
  %                                          ^^^^^^^^
  % This should not be \topskip but something else, but I don't know what.
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht\scratchboxone+\dp\scratchboxone\relax>\scratchdimen
    \setbox\scratchboxtwo=\vsplit\scratchboxone to \scratchdimen
    \snaptogrid\hpack{\box\scratchboxtwo}
    \snaptogrid\hpack{\box\scratchboxone}
  \else
    \snaptogrid\hpack{\box\scratchboxone}
  \fi}

\starttext

\samplefile{knuth}

\samplefile{ward}

\samplefile{hawking}

\samplefile{knuth}

\startnogrid
  \blank[small]
  \samplefile{ward}
  \blank[small]
  \samplefile{knuth}
  \blank[small]
  \samplefile{knuth}
  \blank[small]
\stopnogrid

\samplefile{ward}

\samplefile{hawking}

\stoptext
```

[image]